# How to get max/min element from a boost multiarray

Tags: c++, boost, boost-multi-array

I'm wondering a simple way to find the maximum/minimum element of a boost multiarray, an object of 3 indices as the following:

```
int iDepth=10,iWidth=10,iHeight=10;
boost::multi_array<GLfloat, 3> image(boost::extents[iDepth][iWidth][iHeight]);
```

Comment: `std::min_element` and `std::max_element` should do the trick.

Comment: Yes, but I don't understand the form of iterators to pass to this STL functions.

Answer (score 2):

This should work :

```
std::max_element( image.origin(), image.origin() + image.num_elements());
```

Comment: This is not correct for array that do not start at `[0][0]...`. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using member `data()` is more correct because:

1. ensures that `image` is actually a contiguous (compact array).
2. scans from the beginning of the array, even if the first elements is not `[0][0]...`. (`origin()` means the address of `[0][0]...` even if the array "starts" at a different point, e.g. `[1][1]...`.

```
std::max_element( image.data(), image.data() + image.num_elements());
```

Answer (score -2):

Did you try something like:

```
std::max_element( image.begin(), image.end());
```

Comment: What should I expect as return type of this function with such iterators as input?

Comment: Check the documentation, for example from here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/max_element/

Comment: The iterators return a multi_array of the next lower dimension which is clearly not what the OP wants a maximum of.